# Adding a new name/item to a list and calling that variable globally?

Tags: numbers, append, extends, custom-lists

I'm pretty much brand new to coding and decided to start with  Python.  I have been working on a simple "Number Guessing Game" and have evolved it a bit more each iteration.

I decided that I want to make it a little bit more robust that just finishing after the number is guessed.

I want the user/player to enter their name, have that name stored, and then used throughout... until the end, when they're asked if they want to play again and if it's the 'same user?" and if they say, "No.", I want it to append a new name to the list and then go through the game again.

This is what I've got so far... please be gentle... I know there's some errors :(

```
        import sys
        import os
        import random
        global player


        while True:
            def GuessingGame():
        player = []
        player.append(input("Please Enter Your Name:\n")),
        # player_name = input("Please enter your name: \n")
        print(f"Hello, {player[0]}! Let's get started!\n")
        number = 500
        count = 1
        guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 1000: \n"))

        while guess != number:
            count += 1
            if guess > (number + 10):
            print("TOO HIGH, a little lower...")
            elif guess < (number - 10):
                print("TOO LOW... guess higher!")
            elif guess > (number + 5):
                print("You're getting warmer, but still TOO HIGH, a little lower...")
            elif guess < (number - 5):
                print("You're getting warmer, but still TOO LOW...  higher!")
            elif guess < number:
                print("You're REALLY warm, but still a bit TOO LOW")
            elif guess > number:
                print("You're REALLY, but still a bit TOO HIGH")
            guess = int(input("Try again...\n"))
        if guess == number:
            print(f"You got it!!! It took you {count} tries to guess {number}\n")
            response1 = str(input("Would you like to try again? Y or N\n"))
            if response1 == ("y" or "Y"):
                 sameplayer = str(input("Is this still {player[0]}? Y1 or N1\n"))
                 if sameplayer == ("y1" or "Y1"):
                    GuessingGame()
                 else:
                    newplayer = player.extend(str(input("Please Enter New Player's Name:\n")))
                    print(f"Hello, {player[1]}!, Let's Get Started!")

        return
        GuessingGame()

Again, this is the first time I'm sharing anything I've done... so please don't just wreck me :)
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation!

Comment: Do you know a good way to copy/paste the code into this medium?  I tried to do that but it didn't work... is there a pinned message perhaps as to how I can do that more appropriately?
TIA

Comment: well, you copy paste your code, then selected and hit ctrl+k

Comment: Your code doesn't have a correct flow, you are using recursive function where they are not intended to be used, try using loops instead, also be sure to check the guess before asking for another try as you do on "        guess = int(input("Try again...\n"))
", you can draw a flowchart explaining the flow of your program, that could really help you improve your program designing.

Comment: I just recopied and pasted the code with "ctrl-K"... please tell me if it works any better for you...

As for your suggestion to make a "flow chart", I did exactly that... and what I came up with was:
Player enter's their name - Player is greeted - Player is asked to guess a number between 1:1000... if they're within 10 numbers, plus or minus, they're told they're close, and if they're within 5, plus or minus, they're really warm. - After they guess, they're asked to play again? - If Yes, they're asked if they're still Player - If No, they're asked to enter a new name - Game begins again.

Comment: why do you have a list for appending names?

Answer (score 0):

Here i copy the same code you wrote, but with a little bit of modifications that i felt were needed to be made.

```
from random import randint

player = None

def GuessingGame():
    global player
    if player is None:
        player = input("Please Enter Your Name:\n")
    print(f"Hello, {player}! Let's get started!\n")
    number = randint(1, 1000)
    guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 1000: \n"))
    count = 1
    while guess != number:
        if guess > (number + 10):
            print("TOO HIGH, a little lower...")
        elif guess < (number - 10):
            print("TOO LOW... guess higher!")
        elif guess > (number + 5):
            print("You're getting warmer, but still TOO HIGH, a little lower...")
        elif guess < (number - 5):
            print("You're getting warmer, but still TOO LOW...  higher!")
        elif guess < number:
            print("You're REALLY warm, but still a bit TOO LOW")
        elif guess > number:
            print("You're REALLY, but still a bit TOO HIGH")
        if guess == number:
            break
        else:
            count += 1
            guess = int(input("Try again...\n"))

    print(f"You got it!!! It took you {count} tries to guess {number}\n")
    response1 = str(input("Would you like to try again? Y or N\n"))
    if response1.lower() == 'y':
        sameplayer = str(input(f"Is this still {player}? Y or N\n"))
        if sameplayer.lower() == 'n':
            player = None
            return
        else:
            return

while True:
    GuessingGame()
```

Let me know if you got any questions.